# Can the conditional distribution $P(\cdot |\mathcal{G})$ be a probability measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and some sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$. Can the conditional distribution

$$P(A|\mathcal{G})=E_P[1_{A}|\mathcal{G}],\quad\text{for }A\in\mathcal{F}$$

be an actual probability measure on $\mathcal{G}$ and be used as such? For example for a random variable $X$, we would have

$$P(X\in A|\mathcal{G})=P(\cdot|\mathcal{G})(X^{-1}(A))\quad$$

and so forth?

Or let me ask in another way: *Should* I understand a conditional distribution as an *hypothetical* distribution?

Comment: Yes, it is a probability measure on the space.

Comment: Well, it's actually a random variable, not a probability measure. But I wonder how these could coincide.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_probability might be an answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value $P(A|\mathcal G)$ is a $\mathcal G$-measurable function, not a number.  So $A \mapsto P(A|\mathcal G)$ is not a measure.

You might attempt a "disintegration" where, for each $\omega \in \Omega$, the set-function $A \mapsto P(A|\mathcal G)(\omega)$ is a probability measure defined on $\mathcal F$.  [Search "disintegration" to find conditions under which this can be done.]

Note, it is not very interesting on $\mathcal G$, since when $A \in \mathcal G$, we have $P(A|\mathcal G) = \mathbf1_{A}$.

Comment: Oh, yes, since $1_A$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, $P(A|\mathcal{G})=E[1_A|\mathcal{G}]=1_A$.

Comment: Yes, it's not a measure. However, if $X$ takes values in a Polish space, one can find a Markov kernel, such that $P(\cdot|\mathcal{G})(\omega)=\kappa(\cdot,\omega)$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$. Unfortunately, I only found this resource in german: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reguläre_bedingte_Verteilung#Existenz

Comment: Polish space is good for disintegration, yes.  I know the explanation in P. Billingsley, *Probability and measure*.